# flatpickr via rails importmap not being generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

Attempting to use flatpickr as a UI for setting a date field with Rails 7.0.1 and ruby 3.1.  When clicking on the input field, the expected 2 months of calendars is not rendered & in fact, nothing is registered in the browser network tab.

After `bin/importmap pin flatpickr` rails pinned the library to the cdn in the `importmap.rb` file:

```
pin "flatpickr", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:flatpickr@4.6.9/dist/flatpickr.js"
```

`application.js` has the initially generated `import "controllers"`.

`flatpickr_controller.rb` was created in the javascript/controllers directory with

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import flatpickr from "flatpickr"

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.config = {
      enableTime: false,
      dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
    }
  }
}
```

The view partial invokes:

```
<%= form_with model: promo do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :date_from, placeholder: t(".select"), data: { controller:  "flatpickr" } %>
<% end %>
```

while the controller sets

```
    @promos = Promo.up_comings(60)
    @promo = Promo.new
    @next_promo = Promo.next
    @dates_to_disable = @promos.pluck(:date_from)
```

Why is the calendar not rendering?
I am also confused as to where to place the different flatpickr options: in the controller, or straight into the form date element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is related to support for Stimulus 3. Pin as follows:
`bin/importmap pin stimulus-flatpickr@beta`

Also reference some css source, such as to the latest version
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:flatpickr@4.6.9/dist/flatpickr.min.css">`
otherwise the input field will be deemed as readonly...